# How to find the largest area among N rectangles

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, struct, geometry

The main task is to generate 3 rectangles using two points (top left and bottom right of each) and determinate the largest area among them.

Partially, I have already completed the task using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct Rectangle {
    struct Point topLeft;
    struct Point botRight;
};

int Area (struct Rectangle r) {

    int length, breadth;
    length = r.botRight.x - r.topLeft.x;
    breadth = r.topLeft.y - r.botRight.y;

    return length * breadth;
}
int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    struct Rectangle r1, r2, r3;
   
    r1.topLeft.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    r1.topLeft.y = -50 + rand() % 101;
    r1.botRight.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    r1.botRight.y = -50 + rand() % 101;

    while (r1.botRight.x <= r1.topLeft.x) {
        r1.botRight.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    }
    while (r1.topLeft.y <= r1.botRight.y) {
        r1.topLeft.y = -50 + rand() % 101;
    }
    printf("\t----------RECTANGLE 1----------\n");
    printf("\tTop left point is x = %d y = %d\n", r1.topLeft.x, r1.topLeft.y);
    printf("\tBottom right point is x = %d y = %d\n", r1.botRight.x, r1.botRight.y);
    printf("\tArea is %d\n", Area(r1));
    
    r2.topLeft.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    r2.topLeft.y = -50 + rand() % 101;
    r2.botRight.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    r2.botRight.y = -50 + rand() % 101;

    while (r2.botRight.x <= r2.topLeft.x) {
        r2.botRight.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    }
    while (r2.topLeft.y <= r2.botRight.y) {
        r2.topLeft.y = -50 + rand() % 101;
    }
    printf("\t----------RECTANGLE 2----------\n");
    printf("\tTop left point is x = %d y = %d\n", r2.topLeft.x, r2.topLeft.y);
    printf("\tBottom right point is x = %d y = %d\n", r2.botRight.x, r2.botRight.y);
    printf("\tArea is %d\n", Area(r2));
    
    r3.topLeft.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    r3.topLeft.y = -50 + rand() % 101;
    r3.botRight.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    r3.botRight.y = -50 + rand() % 101;

    while (r3.botRight.x <= r3.topLeft.x) {
        r3.botRight.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    }
    while (r3.topLeft.y <= r3.botRight.y) {
        r3.topLeft.y = -50 + rand() % 101;
    }
    printf("\t----------RECTANGLE 3----------\n");
    printf("\tTop left point is x = %d y = %d\n", r3.topLeft.x, r3.topLeft.y);
    printf("\tBottom right point is x = %d y = %d\n", r3.botRight.x, r3.botRight.y);
    printf("\tArea is %d\n", Area(r3));
    printf("\t-------------------------------\n");
    
    if (Area(r1) >= Area(r2) && Area(r1) >= Area(r3))
        printf("\tRectangle 1 has a biggest area --> %d\n", Area(r1));


    if (Area(r2) >= Area(r1) && Area(r2) >= Area(r3))
        printf("\tRectangle 2 has a biggest area --> %d\n", Area(r2));


    if (Area(r3) >= Area(r1) && Area(r3) >= Area(r2))
        printf("\tRectangle 3 has a biggest area --> %d\n", Area(r3));
```

But I'm very confused about how to do this task if there are, for example, 50 rectangles?)

There is what i've already done:
I've created the function of generatig the points of each rectangle (genRec) in order to generate 50 rectangles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct Rectangle {
    struct Point topLeft;
    struct Point botRight;
};

int Area(struct Rectangle r) {

    int length, breadth;
    length = r.botRight.x - r.topLeft.x;
    breadth = r.topLeft.y - r.botRight.y;

    return length * breadth;
}
int genRec();

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
        printf("\t----------RECTANGLE %d----------\n" , i);
        genRec();

    }

}
int genRec() {
    struct Rectangle  rec;
   
    rec.topLeft.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    rec.topLeft.y = -50 + rand() % 101;
    rec.botRight.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    rec.botRight.y = -50 + rand() % 101;

    while (rec.botRight.x <= rec.topLeft.x) {
        rec.botRight.x = -50 + rand() % 101;
    }
    while (rec.topLeft.y <= rec.botRight.y) {
        rec.topLeft.y = -50 + rand() % 101;
    }
    printf("\tTop left point is x = %d y = %d\n", rec.topLeft.x, rec.topLeft.y);
    printf("\tBottom right point is x = %d y = %d\n", rec.botRight.x, rec.botRight.y);
    printf("\tArea is %d\n", Area(rec));

    return 0;
}
```

But, i have no idea how to compare the areas of each rectangle easily, without eternal comparing using "if" because Area(rec) is an only one variable, but with differnt numbers.

I will be glad for any help, don't judge harshly, I'm just a begginer)

Comment: My question to you is: Did you even read the answer I provided to your question a week ago? The solution to this problem is there...

Comment: yeah, but the answer does not actually satisfy certain conditions of the task

Comment: I see nothing in the previous question or this question indicating there are constraining conditions on the coding solution. Please edit your question and add those.

Comment: @dan1chX "i have no idea how to compare the areas of each rectangle easily," is too broad.

Comment: @dan1chX Consider if `r1.topLeft.x == 50`.  Do you  then see a problem with `while (r1.botRight.x <= r1.topLeft.x) { r1.botRight.x = -50 + rand() % 101; }`?

Comment: @Fe2O3 I didn't see your comment about your answer on OP's other question when I answered below. But, there are some aspects of your method that I liked better [than mine].

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks. Just seems cleaner, to me, to deal with edges instead of vertices and keep the values "positive", only offsetting when printing... There are unmentioned caveats about RAND_MAX, but that's for another day... `:-)` My "days-ago" answer dealt with "bottomLeft" and "topRight" leaving something for the OP to contribute... `:-)`

Comment: Is the problem just to compute the area of every rectangle, then return the maximum of all the areas computed? And you already now how to compute an area. So all you have to do now is compute the maximum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you *can't* just:

1. Generate the "lower" coordinate (in a given dimension, either X or Y).
2. *then* loop on the "upper" coordinate (in the given dimension) until it is larger.

If the "lower" is *ever* the maximum, the program will loop infinitely because the "upper" can *never* be greater than the "lower".

One solution is to generate a *pair* of numbers (e.g. `lo` and `hi`) and loop if `lo >= hi`. The key difference is the loop will regenerate the `lo` value on each iteration.

In other words, if the range is bad, reject *both* lower and upper numbers and try again.

A helper function to generate a pair can help.

Below is the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct Rectangle {
    struct Point topLeft;
    struct Point botRight;
};

int
Area(const struct Rectangle *r)
{
    int length, breadth;

    length = r->botRight.x - r->topLeft.x;
    if (length <= 0)
        exit(1);

    breadth = r->topLeft.y - r->botRight.y;
    if (breadth <= 0)
        exit(2);

    return length * breadth;
}

int genRec(void);

int
main(void)
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
        printf("\t----------RECTANGLE %d----------\n", i);
        genRec();

    }

    return 0;
}

void
genPair(int *lo,int *hi)
{
    while (1) {
        *lo = -50 + rand() % 101;
        *hi = -50 + rand() % 101;
        if (*lo < *hi)
            break;
    }
}

int
genRec(void)
{
    struct Rectangle rec;

    genPair(&rec.topLeft.x,&rec.botRight.x);
    genPair(&rec.botRight.y,&rec.topLeft.y);

    printf("\tTop left point is x = %d y = %d\n",
        rec.topLeft.x, rec.topLeft.y);
    printf("\tBottom right point is x = %d y = %d\n",
        rec.botRight.x, rec.botRight.y);
    printf("\tArea is %d\n", Area(&rec));

    return 0;
}
```

---

As to determining the *maximum* area of all the rectangles, you calculate the area with `Area` but just print it.

We can return this value to `main`. It can retain/remember the maximum area and its corresponding rectangle index.

One issue with the original code in this regard is that `genRec` uses a function scoped variable `rec`. We want to have this be a *pointer* argument so `main` can populate an array.

Here is the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct Rectangle {
    struct Point topLeft;
    struct Point botRight;
    int area;
};

int
Area(const struct Rectangle *r)
{
    int length, breadth;

    length = r->botRight.x - r->topLeft.x;
    if (length <= 0)
        exit(1);

    breadth = r->topLeft.y - r->botRight.y;
    if (breadth <= 0)
        exit(2);

    return length * breadth;
}

int genRec(struct Rectangle *rec);

int
main(void)
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    int maxarea = -1;
    int maxidx = -1;
    struct Rectangle rec[50];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(rec) / sizeof(rec[0]); i++) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("\t----------RECTANGLE %d----------\n", i + 1);
        int area = genRec(&rec[i]);

        if (area > maxarea) {
            maxarea = area;
            maxidx = i;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("\tMaximum area is %d in rectangle %d\n",maxarea,maxidx + 1);

    return 0;
}

void
genPair(int *lo,int *hi)
{
    while (1) {
        *lo = -50 + rand() % 101;
        *hi = -50 + rand() % 101;
        if (*lo < *hi)
            break;
    }
}

int
genRec(struct Rectangle *rec)
{

    genPair(&rec->topLeft.x,&rec->botRight.x);
    genPair(&rec->botRight.y,&rec->topLeft.y);

    printf("\tTop left point is x = %d y = %d\n",
        rec->topLeft.x, rec->topLeft.y);
    printf("\tBottom right point is x = %d y = %d\n",
        rec->botRight.x, rec->botRight.y);

    int area = Area(rec);
    printf("\tArea is %d\n", area);

    return area;
}
```

Comment: Unfinished business... `area` is a member of `Rectangle`, but has no value assigned in the final version... `:-)`